# How to cancel an asynchronous Task?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a method that loads data, eg.:

```
public async GetCustomers()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
            customers = customerRequest.GetCustomers();
    });
}
```

`customerRequest` is a simple class that uses `HttpClient` to connect to a WebApi server. The call stack is as follows:

> method->request->controller action->server layer->repository->db

Currently, the controller action returns `IHttpActionResult`, whilst the service and repository layers return `IEnumerable<Customer>`. All methods are called synchronously.

For testing purposes, I added the `for` loop to increase the task's delay and see the SQL statements being executed.

If the user decides to close the form, the task is still being executed in the background and the SQL statements are still sent to the db.

What is the correct way to cancel such a task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use `CancellationTokenSource`, and pass its `CancellationToken` into your method. When the form closes, call `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel`.

Note, however, that you want to pass the `CancellationToken` into the methods that actually use it. As I describe on my blog, [`Task.Run` is not one of them](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html).

What you really want to do is start at the lowest level (on the client side), and pass the `CancellationToken` into whatever `HttpClient` method that you're using (i.e., [like this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551747(v=vs.118).aspx)).

Then work your way up. I'd also recommend making your code asynchronous. When you're done, you should end up with a `GetCustomers` that looks like this:

```
public async Task GetCustomersAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    customers = await customerRequest.GetCustomersAsync(token);
}
```

If you want to Really Be Sure (tm) that no spurious requests go out, you can also explicitly check the token before doing the request:

```
public async Task GetCustomersAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
  {
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    customers = await customerRequest.GetCustomersAsync(token);
  }
}
```

You can also [handle cancellation on the server side](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CancelToken) if that's important to you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout CancellationTokenSource. You can keep one of these long lived and a button or a close event call Cancel() on it. It just needs to be passed to all your tasks if you want them all to cancel. The task will throw an exception so make sure you wrap in a try catch. You can also check if a cancel request has been made within your task to try to break out in a graceful manor.

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //do work, will throw if cts.Cancel() is called
}, cts.Token);

//wait 2 seconds then cancel
await Task.Delay(2000);

cts.Cancel();
```